# Shrinking dictionaries in Julia

Tags: dictionary, memory-management, julia

I'm interested in using dictionaries in an application where the contents of the dictionaries are modified very frequently, i.e. `key => value` pairs are created, deleted, and moved from one dictionary to another. An issue I see is that Julia dictionaries don't shrink, and am afraid of the memory usage getting very bad if these dictionaries become large.

Are there better datatypes, or packages, that I could look towards in this scenario? A dictionary like datatype that is better suited to dynamic modification?

I've seen that `sizehint!` now supports shrinking for arrays, but I don't believe the same is true for dicts? Perhaps a custom datatype based on arrays with the functionality I am after is a way to go...?

**Edit**:

The application is to model dynamic, weighted, multi-layer graphs. I'm interested in modelling multi-layer graphs with hundreds of nodes and edges, where the connectivity and weights of each layer may rapidly change. Changes on one layer lead to changes on other layers (movement of data between layers).

Comment: There is `delete!` for dictionaries. But honestly, constantly modifying (and resizing) dictionaries doesn't really sound like a well designed program, potentially with quite poor performance. Are you sure that you can't solve your problem in another way?

Comment: More details would help... how large are the dictionaries? How often are items deleted and inserted? Are keys reused? For every usage profile there is a chance of a better fitting data structure.

Comment: For sure, my fear is that dictionary-based approach will lead to bad performance which is what prompted my question! I've added some additional context.

Comment: If you are modelling graphs, why don't you use Graphs.jl, MultiLayerGraphs.jl or any of the other related packages?

Comment: For most cases a vector of vectors is the best data structure for modelling of graphs. Also usually you will want some data redundancy. See how SimpleGraph and SimpleDiGraph are coded in Graphs.jl

Answer (score 1):

As of Julia 1.9, `sizehint!` shrinks dictionaries (see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/8e630552924eac54c809aa7bc30871c7df1582d3/base/dict.jl#L219).